# Spring @Value is null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Like the Title says, my @Value doesn't passes a value

I've written the following in my application.properties:

```
project:
  image:
    path= "C:\\Users\\...."
```

I've got a Class Configuration

```
@Component
public class Configuration{
    @Value("${project.image.path}")
    public static String ImagePath;
}
```

In my Other class called Image I want to convert the String path to a File, so that I can work with this value later:

```
public class Image{
    static File Directory= new File (Configuration.ImagePath);
}
```

The Problem is, when I use my programm and one of the Methods is used, where the variable Directory is used(which are all written in the Image class), I get a NullPointerException: null and strangely when I refresh the site after the error occurs one time, the error now says NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.Project.Image

Comment: I think it should be `project.image.path= "C:\\Users\\..` remove colon and set  `.`

Comment: still doesn't work, but thanks

Comment: Have you autowired in Image class `@Autowire Configuration?`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use @Value on static properties. Either remove the static keyword or
make a non static setter for your static variable:

```
@Component
public class Configuration {

    private static String imagePath;

    @Value("${project.image.path}")
    public void setImagePath(String value) {
        this.imagePath = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You! This worked for me!